# Wordpress Shortcode to call latest posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom page template to display the latest 12 posts with their respective title and excerpt, but I tought that It would be easier if I could call this with a shortcode.

This is the loop in "post-grid.php" which calls to those 3 things.

```
<section class="post-grid">
    <?php
        $grid = array('post_per_page' => 12);
        $query = new WP_Query( $grid );
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    ?>
<div class="grid-posts">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2><br>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured'); ?><br>
    <?php the_excerpt() ?><br>
</div>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
</section>
```

How can I create a shortcode that executes that loop?

I know how to add a shortcode using

```
add_shortcode('postGrid', 'postGrid');
function postGrid()
{
 //Code here
}
```

But im not sure how to implement the above as a function. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?php

  $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => 12,
   'paged' => $page,
   );

 query_posts($args);?>
 hope this will help you :)

 Point related to add Post Thumbnail:

 // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it. 
 <?php if (has_post_thumbnail() ) {
 the_post_thumbnail();
 } the_content(); ?>
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: Hey this works! but how can I add the thumbnails? also when I wrap the post in divs it gives me 500 server error!

Comment: Your welcome and going to update the point for add thumbnails.
// check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
      <?php  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
 the_post_thumbnail();
        } 
        the_content(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't editing any code - you are creating your own - just put all that code in the call back function as is and it should work.

```
add_shortcode('postGrid', 'postGrid');
function postGrid()
{
    <section class="post-grid">
        <?php
            $grid = array('post_per_page' => 12);
            $query = new WP_Query( $grid );
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        ?>
    <div class="grid-posts">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2><br>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured'); ?><br>
        <?php the_excerpt() ?><br>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    </section>
}
```

Comment: I did it but I get 500 Server error and i'm running my site in localhost!